# Entity Framework with MySQL - Contains method throws exception when more than one element is passed as parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mysql-connector

Here I'm using **Contains** to create **IN** statement:

```
public static List<Identity> GetIdentity(dbEntities db, string[] types)
{
    var query = (
     from au in db.user
     from c in db.career
     .Where(x => x.emp_nb == au.emp_nb).DefaultIfEmpty()
     .Where(x => types.Contains(x.type)) // here it is!
     select new Identity
     {
         userlogin = au.User_Login,
         first_name = au.User_First_Name,
         last_name = au.User_Last_Name,
     }
     ).Distinct();

    return query.ToList();
}
```

This works great when `types` array has one element.

When it has **two or more elements** during the debuggin session I get:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDB3117788 (KernelBase.dll) in
>   Migration_Module.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x0000000000000018.

and the excpetion is thrown:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.AddDefaultColumns(Scope scope)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.Wrap(Scope scope)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbApplyExpression expression)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbDistinctExpression expression)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression)
   en MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
   en MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   en System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   en System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   en System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   en System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   en System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   en System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   en SF_Migration_Module.queries.Queries.GetIdentity(dbEntities db, String[] types)
```

I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Entity Framework 5
- MySQL NET Connector 6.9.9

Comment: MySQL connector is famous for it's bugs (just like MySQL itself) - so I'd check their bug tracker and if nothing found - report that. Of course best would be to stop using MySQL, but that is not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to EntityFramework 6 solved my problem.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.9.9
```